# Package libdw was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I'm trying to build a Rust based gstreamer plugin. but I got these errors:

```
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gstreamer-1.0" "gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.14"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1

error: failed to run custom build command for `gstreamer-sys v0.17.0 (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs#d203745c)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/saeed/clean/media-plugins/target/release/build/gstreamer-sys-ce7fd93e56356a79/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GSTREAMER_1.0_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GSTREAMER_1.0_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GSTREAMER_1.0_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:warning=`"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gstreamer-1.0" "gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.14"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  --- stdout


  --- stderr
  Package libdw was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libdw.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  Package 'libdw', required by 'gstreamer-1.0', not found
  Package 'libdw', required by 'gstreamer-1.0', not found

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

The last lines say I need to install libdw, but I couldn't find any library like `libdw`. My box is Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4

Comment: probably `apt-get install libdw-dev`

Comment: @kmdreko On a Red Hat box. I couldn't find any library like dw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Red Hat Enterprise I had to install this package:

```
sudo yum install elfutils-devel
```